# How to find length of the return type in recursive function

Tags: php, algorithm, depth-first-search

While going through the code, it written for DFS something like I have shown below.
I want to get the length of the each traversal , how can I use the static variable to get the return value,

```
<?php 

.....
.....

    while loop start


    {
    //
    // some code
    //

    $deletebranch = json_encode($todel);
    echo $deletebranch;

    foreach ($abc as $key => $xyz)
    {
    ///
    /// code for finding $letter, $array_node 
    ///
    $finaldepthsearchgraph[$letter]['vertex'] = $letter;
    $finaldepthsearchgraph[$letter]['visited'] = false;
    $finaldepthsearchgraph[$letter]['letter'] = $letter;
    $finaldepthsearchgraph[$letter]['neighbours'] = $array_node;
    ///
    ///
    }


    depthFirstSearch($finaldepthsearchgraph['A'], $finaldepthsearchgraph);

    } // end of while loop


        function depthFirstSearch($vertex, $list )
        {

            if (!$vertex['visited']) {
                echo $vertex['letter'];
                //var_dump($list);
                 // output on screen
                // mark vertex as visited
                $list[$vertex['vertex']]['visited'] = true;
                foreach ($vertex['neighbours'] as $neighbour) {
                    // Watch neighbours, which were not visited yet
                    if (!$list[$neighbour]['visited']) {
                        // going through neighbour-vertexes
                        $list = depthFirstSearch(
                            $list[$neighbour], 
                            $list
                        );
                    }

                }
            }


            return $list;

        }


....
?>
```

#### ANSWER

The Out Put I am getting is, I need to find the length to use it later in the code, please dont suggest any other DFS method, I have to carry through this only.

```
["A","B"]

ACBFGHL  

["B","C"]

ABCFGHL

["A","C"]

ABCFGHL

["C","F"]

ABC

["F","G"]

ABCF

["G","H"]

ABCFGLH

["H","L"]

ABCFGHL

["G","L"]

ABCFGHL
```

Comment: Return not the array, but `SearchResult` class instance which holds the list, the traversal path and anything else you like.

Comment: @zerkms  How? Please explain

Comment: substitute `return $list;` with returning some custom object that not only holds the actual list but any additional information you need.

Comment: where to edit in above code .. I am striking my head out of overdose .. or need to change whole dfs part?

Comment: return list is getting passed recursively that is causing error

Comment: "return list is getting passed recursively" --- I don't see any reason why you can pass array in a recursive call, but cannot pass some other type (including a custom object)